# How to call functions from another php file?

Tags: php, mysql, function, csv

In short: I am uploading to */var/tmp* multiple excel files, then convert them into .csv(2 different converters for .xls and .xlsx). The resulting file, result.csv should be inserted into database. It all worked until we decided to **allow to upload multiple files simultaneously**(adding multiple attribute to html input tag). **Problem: data not inserted into table**

```
<?php
// database connection goes here;
include 'convertt2a.php';
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$updir = "/var/tmp/result.xlsx";
$n= count($_FILES['rawexcel']['name']);
for ($i=0; $i<$n; $i++)    {
$upfile = $updir.basename($_FILES['rawexcel']['name'][$i]);
$ext = pathinfo ($_FILES['rawexcel']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(is_uploaded_file ($_FILES ["rawexcel"]["tmp_name"][$i]))
{
 move_uploaded_file ($_FILES["rawexcel"]["tmp_name"][$i], $updir);
if ($ext == 'xlsx' ) {   exec("/usr/local/bin/cnvt   /var/tmp/result.xlsx      /var/tmp/result.csv "); } else 
 if ($ext == 'xls' ) {   exec("/usr/local/bin/xls2csv -x   /var/tmp/result.xls* -b WINDOWS-1251 -c /var/tmp/result.csv -a UTF-8"); } 
 echo "File  successfully uploaded and converted to .csv ";
  } 
else {
 echo "error uploading file ".$upfile;}

if (isset($_POST['provider'])) {
//select action to perform on case of different providers
if ($_POST['provider']=='tele2altel'){echo t2a("tele2");}
} 
 echo "cycle ".$i."ended here; </br>";
 }}
 else {echo "not isset post method";}
  ?>
```

t2a function:

```
function t2a ($string){

//opening .csv file, inserting into table in SAMPLEBANK TELE2ALTEL
$row =0;
if (($handle = fopen("/var/tmp/result.csv", "r"))!==FALSE){
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ","))!==FALSE) {
$row ++;
//we got data in $data[$i] array
if ($row==4) {$idb=$data[2];}
if ($row >6) {
$da=$data[0]; $imei = $data[1]; $ab=$data[2];$ty = NULL;
$du=$data[6]; $op = $data[3];$dir =$data[5];
$num= strlen($dir);
if ($num>=28) {$ty= $dir; $dir=NULL;}
if ($ab!==''){
$sql= "INSERT INTO tele2altel(Abonent,Opponent, Type, Data, Duration,     idBase, IMEI,direction)  
values ('$ab','$op','$ty','$da','$du', '$idb','$imei','$dir')";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);}
}}
fclose($handle);
} else {echo "unable to read file";}
$s = "Successfully inserted into DB";
return $s;
}
```

**My output:** 
File  successfully uploaded and converted to .csv

cycle i ended here;

Successfully inserted into DB, i times(number of files to be uploaded)

I have checked seapartely .csv files, they are being converted correctly. Thus, the error is in t2a function. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Please learn about using prepared statements, they can save a lot of problems with CSV and binding all sorts of data, also it's better for security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that was needed for this code to work was clarification of type of return for function:

```
 function t2a ($string):string {}
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Include the another file in it.

```
<?php include('yourfilename'); ?>
```

Comment: I have done that:

include 'convertt2a.php';
it is the file where my function t2a is located

Answer (score 1):

I think the line below is opening the wrong file...

```
fopen("/var/tmp/result.xlsx", "r")
```

Should be

```
fopen("/var/tmp/result.csv", "r")
```